# slider increment automatically in time period

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uislider

I am trying to use the current time in my movie player to increment a sliders value in my iPad app.

```
slider.maximumValue=10;
slider.minimumValue=0;
```

How can I increment slider.value from 0 to 10 in a specific time period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) to repeatedly add 1 to your slider value if you know the specific time period beforehand:

```
NSTimer *aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(timePeriod/slider.maximumValue)
target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
    [slider setValue:slider.value + 1.0];
    if(slider.value == slider.maximumValue) {
        [theTimer invalidate];
    }
}
```